# Edit text on popup window not showing keyboard in android

Tags: android, popup

i am devloping a android  app where i am taking one popup and on that popup i am puting one edit text but when i run app and tap on edit text keyboard are not shown .. i see some suggestions here but that not work for me following is my code

pop.xml

```
 <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_promo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textSize="24sp">

                    </EditText>
```

in activity

```
 final View popUpView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_add_money_wallet,
            null); // inflating popup layout
    mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true); // Creation of popup
    mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    mpopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mpopup.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); // Displaying popup
    mpopup.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);





    ImageView mCloseIcon = (ImageView) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.close_ic);

    Button btn_pb = (Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pb);
    Button btn_hdfc = (Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btn_hdfc);
    Button btn_cc = (Button)   popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cc);
    TextView tv_promo=(TextView)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.tv_promo);
    final EditText et_promo = (EditText)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.et_promo);
    final Button btn_promo =(Button)popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btn_promo);

    final EditText tvWalletBalance = (EditText) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.tv_wallet_balance);




    tv_promo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            et_promo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_promo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

please anyone tell me how i show keyboard for edittext on popup

Comment: add `et_promo.requestFocus();`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following line from your code should solve the problem:

```
mpopup.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```